# [LwIP][UDP] calling netconn_send() within while(1) loop but message shown only once on Wireshark

Tags: c, tcp, udp, lwip

I'm new to Ethernet and LwIP Stack. I'm trying to send just a simple message within an infinite loop over UDP and track this message over Wireshark on the destination host.

For that I'm doing the following:

```
static void ExampleUDP_thread(void *arg) /*It's a thread in FreeRTOS*/
{
  struct netconn *conn;
  struct netbuf *buf = 0;
  char msg[] = "This is my message! :)"; 
  ip_addr_t remoteAddr;
  IP4_ADDR(&remoteAddr, 192,168,1,188);

  conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_UDP);
  netconn_connect(conn, &remoteAddr, 7000);

  buf = netbuf_new();
  netbuf_ref(buf, msg, sizeof(msg));

  while(1)
  {
    netconn_send(conn, buf); /*Send the message permanently*/
  }
  netbuf_delete(buf);
```

}

I can see on Wireshark that the first packet contains the message but on all packages after it the message is 0000.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: maybe the netbuf is cleared when you send it?

Comment: hmm but when I put the breakpoint on the netconn_send() and read out the buf I see within the payload that the message is there within the memory!

Comment: Even on repeated turns of the loop?

Comment: yes ,the payload is always there